# By default open account entity from lookup new button

Tags: lookup, dynamics-crm-2013

In my form there is a lookup for Specifier account.

but when i click on +new button, it opens new contact form instead of account form.

[image]

**NOTE :** In form design type of that field is "customer".

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for open default entity as following :

```
var newWindow = Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("account");
newWindow.moveTo(0,0);
newWindow.resizeTo(800,600);
```

[XRM.Utility.OpenEntityForm open CRM forms for you](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/crm-2013-let-xrm-utility-openentityform-open-crm-forms-for-you/)

But still not find how to call this lines on click on +new button.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this ?